ufw（Uncomplicated Firewall） と iptablesと nftables　の違いはなんですか？
・nftables　は、iptablesの後継ですか？　上位互換？
・ufw（Uncomplicated Firewall）は、iptablesやnftablesを操作するもの？
大きく4種類ですか？
・ufw（Uncomplicated Firewall）を使用してiptablesを操作？
・ufw（Uncomplicated Firewall）を使用してnftablesを操作？
・iptablesを直接操作？
・nftablesを直接操作？
最終的にやりたいこと
Debian12にファイアウォールを設定したい

re9 さんは当サイトにおいては10年弱で800件近い質問をされているので、最低限 良い質問をするには？ で書かれているポイントは抑えた質問を心がけてほしいです。 / "debian ファイアウォール 設定" で検索するだけでもそれなりの 解説記事 がヒットするし、 UFW と nftables の関係についても書かれています。 / 想像を書き並べて質問を増やすのではなく、"最終的にやりたいこと" をストレートに質問として設定すべきように思います。

Debianのファイアウォールについて知りたいという事でしょうか？それであれば、Debian公式の管理者ハンドブックを確認する事が最も正確かと思います。下記リンク先のドキュメントを参照してください。nftables、iptables、fwbuilder、ufwについてそれぞれ言及されています。
14.2. ファイアウォールとパケットフィルタリング - Debian 管理者ハンドブック
これを読んでも何をしたらいいのかよくわからないというのであれば、Debianを使い続けることは難しいかと思います。
